# La consulta me llega vacia

Tags: c#, orm

Buen día, tengo un problema al realizar una consulta con ormLite en C#. Le envío el formato que está en la base de datos y al hacer debug con el dato que me llega realizo la consulta manualmente en SQL donde encuentra registros.

Este es el código:

Codigo de la clase:

```
// este es la propiedad a la que se hace referencia
 [Alias("VRTR_CIUDADDESTINO")]
        public string DestinationName { get; set; }
```

Este es el metodo que me devuelve la consulta a ejecutar:

```
 public SqlExpression<JournyTransfer> FilterSearch(SqlExpression<JournyTransfer> sql, string column, string filter)
        {
            switch(column)
            {
                case "TransferId":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferId.ToString().Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "OriginName":
                    sql.And(x => x.OriginName.Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "TransferOrigin":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferOrigin.Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "DestinationName":
                    sql.And(x => x.DestinationName.Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "TransferDestination":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferDestination.Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "TransferRegularValue":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferRegularValue.ToString().Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "TransferPrivateValue":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferPrivateValue.ToString().Contains(filter));
                    break;
                case "TransferStatus":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferStatus.Contains(filter));
                    break;
case "ExpirationDate":
    filter = Convert.ToDateTime(filter).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sql.And(x => x.ExpirationDate.ToString().Contains(filter));
    break;
                case "TransferRecommendation":
                    sql.And(x => x.TransferRecommendation.Contains(filter));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return sql;
        }
```

Consulta:

```
var result = filter.FilterSearch(sql, selector, param);
    res.Journeys = db.Select(result);
```

No me da error sólo me llega vacía.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos la sentencia SQL que se ejecuta finalmente? La puedes ver en los logs del servidor o en `sql` debe haber algún método o propiedad para verlo (aunque puede que no, nunca he trabajado con ormLite).

Comment: porque veo un `contains` con una fecha, eso no aplica, es mas convirtes la fecha a string, aun peor

Comment: @LeandroTuttini la propiedad ExpirationDate es de tipo DateTime, el toString() es para que no me marque error en la conversion.

Comment: es que justamente lo que debes comparar son fechas no string, aplicar ese ToString() indica que esta mal lo que comparas y aun peor si usas el contains, no se como esta generandose el sql que se ejecuta por este `ormlite`, pero si debes cambiar el tipo de dato no es correcto